# Add 20 minutes to UTC date

Tags: ios, objective-c, time

I have date in string format,that is with UTC time zone.
I want to add 20 minutes to date.

I am using following code for that:

```
   NSString *strFinal = @"2016-11-21 13:07:04";
   //NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
   //[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss"];
   self.dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
   [self.dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"];
   NSDate *dateFromString = [[NSDate alloc] init];
   [self.dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"]];
   dateFromString = [self.dateFormatter dateFromString:strFinal];
   self.dt = [[NSDate alloc]init];
   self.dt = dateFromString;

   NSTimeInterval secondsInEightHours = 20 * 60;
   //NSDate *dateEightHoursAhead = [dateFromString dateByAddingTimeInterval:secondsInEightHours];
    NSDate *dateEightHoursAhead = [self.dt dateByAddingTimeInterval:secondsInEightHours];

   //after adding 20 mins check
    NSString *strFinaltoPass = [self.dateFormatter stringFromDate:dateEightHoursAhead];
```

but with this date time it gives strFinaltoPass as null.

This works fine with time less than 12 hours but after 12 hour its showing null.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: What is `dateEightHoursAhead` when the string comes back `nil`?

Comment: dateEightHoursAhead is 2016-10-20 00:20:00 +0000 when comes back to nil

Comment: try using `NSDateComponents` and adding 20 minutes to the `minutes` property, you will need to add the logic to increment the hours property if the minutes go above 60... then just convert that back into an `NSDate`

Answer (score 0):

You can use NSCalendar to add minutes, here is an example

```
NSString *strDate = @"2016-11-21 13:07:04";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter1 setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"];

NSDate *dateTemp = [dateFormatter1 dateFromString:strDate];
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

NSDate *dateNew = [calendar dateByAddingUnit:NSCalendarUnitMinute value:20 toDate:dateTemp options:NSCalendarWrapComponents];
```

here `value = 20` is 20 minutes to add in the date